# NDSolve: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following differential equation

```
EOM=(-Piecewise[{{1.157793814828612*^106, r >= 0 && r <= 1.0408060341965232*^-18}, {(9.734399999999999*^36*(2.7912782245116803*^-35 - 3*r^2))/
         (2.7912782245116803*^-35 + r^2)^3, r > 1.0408060341965232*^-18}}, 0])*f[r] + (7*Derivative[1][f][r])/r + Derivative[2][f][r] == 0
```

with initial conditions

```
f[0] == 1
Derivative[1][f][0] == 0
```

numerically using NDSolve

```
NDSolve[{EOM, {f[0] == 1, Derivative[1][f][0] == 0}}, {f[r]}, {r, 0, 100}]
```

But I get

> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.

> Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0 ComplexInfinity encountered.

> NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at r == 0.

I searched other related posts but could not solve the problem. I will be thankful if you help me with this.

Comment: Your `EOM` contains a term `(7*f'[r])/r` which results in `Infinite expression 1/0 encountered` at the initial conditions (`r = 0`).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I actually tried multiplying the whole equation by `r` but that did not help and I still get the same error. @Bob Hanlon

Comment: A little besides the point, but the numbers you have seem a bit wacky - they span 141 orders of magnitude which will likely create some numerical issues for you. Are you sure they're correct?

Comment: Change the initial conditions to `{f[epsilon] == 1, f'[epsilon] == 0}` for a sufficiently small `epsilon`

Comment: Yes, they are correct. The function pieces are of the same order of magnitude and also all the terms added up are of the same order of magnitude. So, in principle the equation is Okay. @bRost03

Comment: @BobHanlon     Thank you, taking 'r<<1' instead of 'r=0' removes errors but I am worried that there might be a deviation from the solution which can affect my results. I would be very happy if I could enter boundary conditions at 'r=0'.

Comment: You can use the asymptotic expansion of the solution at $r\rightarrow0$ to create a piecewise definition of $f’(r)/r$, but you run into a problem that @bRost03 foreshadowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *may* be an answer to an approximation to your question.  *I am making assumptions.*

In addition to the problem at r=0, the derivative of your piecewise function is zero when r=0.  The this gives you a solution:

```
DSolve[{(7 Derivative[1][f][r])/r + (f^\[Prime]\[Prime])[r] == 0, 
  f'[0] == 0, f[0] == 1}, f, r]
```

and so the integrator isn't going to behave well near zero.

It look to me like you are approximating a potential that looks like this:

```
pot = a/r^5 - b/r^3
```

which gives you a force that looks like this.

```
force = -Simplify[D[pot, r]]
```

which looks like your piecewise function.  *Please forgive me for making assumptions about what you are doing.*

Continuing..

This problem is begging to be rescaled to non-dimensional units.
Let's suppose the mininum potential (-eMin) is located at rMin

```
solNorm = 
 Solve[{rMin == SolveValues[force == 0, r][[2]], 
    eMin == pot /. r -> rMin}, {a, b}][[1]]
    eNorm = Simplify[((pot /. r -> rho rMin)/eMin) /. solNorm]
```

That gives a normalized force term (to get units, multiply by Emin/rMin)

```
fNorm = - D[eNorm, rho]
```

With the assumption, your equation of motion becomes

```
eom = phi[rho] fNorm + 7 D[phi[rho], rho]/rho + D[phi[rho], {rho, 2}]
```

Note that starting the equation of motion at pho=0 is going to make phi fly off to infinity.
Using @Bob Hanlon's advice, here is a function to get a numerical solution for different starting points.

```
phiSol[sp_] := 
 phiSol[sp] = 
  NDSolveValue[{eom == 0, phi'[sp] == 0, phi[sp] == 1}, 
   phi, {rho, sp, 2}]
```

For example:

```
phiSol[.1]
```

We will need to extract the domain of the InterpolationFunction

```
Needs["DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`"];
```

The behavior can be investigated for different initial points:

```
Manipulate[
 With[{interpolator = phiSol[sp], 
   domain = Flatten[InterpolatingFunctionDomain[phiSol[sp]]]},
  Plot[interpolator[t], {t, domain[[1]], domain[[2]]}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"r/rMin", "phi"}]
  ],
 {{sp, .5}, .01, 1}
 ]
```

[image: example]
Note that the length unit is rMin which is very small in your original problem.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar problem.  So I use answer space to tell you my numerical experiments.

Suppose that the solution $f(r)$ is even in $r$, then we may define
$F(r^2):=f(r)$.  Thus
$$\partial_{rr}f(r)=\partial_{rr}F(r^2)=2F'(q)+4qF''(q),\quad q=r^2\tag{1}$$
$$\partial_{r}f(r)=\partial_{r}F(r^2)=2rF'(q),\quad\tfrac1r\partial_{r}f(r)=\tfrac1r\partial_{r}F(r^2)=2F'(q),\quad q=r^2\tag{2}$$

Thus EOM becomes a second order ODE for $F(q)$:
$$0=A(q)F(q)+7*2F'(q)+2F'(q)+4qF''(q),\quad q=r^2\tag{3}$$

When I use the boundary condition $F(0)=1,F'(0)=0$ to NDSolve (3), I also got "Infinity expression 1/0 encountered". This is probably due to the term $4qF''(q)$. I then used boundary condition, suggested by
Bob Hanlon,
$F(\epsilon)=1,F'(\epsilon)=0$ and was able to get solution but with different error message "At q == 1.0832772008198944`*^-38, step size is effectively zero;
singularity or stiff system suspected".  In theory the boundary condition $\partial_{r}f(0)==2rF'(q)|_{q=r^2=0}$ is automatically satisfied, no additional requirement is necessary on $F'(0)$.  But if I do not specify $F'(0)$, the NDSolve won't work.

Another thing you may try is to substitute $F(q)=a_0 +q G(q)$ to get an ODE for $G(q)$.

Hope it helps
-Mike